# Can I use a conditional statement in a printf statement?

Tags: java

My code contains a switch statement, and in all cases there are if else statements. They are all pretty short so I was thinking about condensing the code by turning them into conditional statements. The format I was going for was...

```
System.out.printf( (conditional-Statement ) );
```

Here is my if else statement for one of the cases...

```
    if (count == 1) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", count);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%11d", count);
    }
```

Something like...

```
System.out.print((count == 1) ? count : "  " + count);
```

does not produce syntax errors,

but it all messed up when I did...

```
System.out.printf((count == 1) ?  "%3d", count : "%11d", count);
```

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: the if-else version looks better to me in this case

Comment: Completely agreed with @bayou.io After turned that condition into ternary operator, I feel `if-else` is more readable.

Comment: What are you switching against? You might also be able to code everything in an `enum`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But remind that the ternary operator only returns one value, *not two*. What you are trying to do must be done like this:

```
System.out.printf((count == 1) ?  "%3d" : "%11d", count);
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be

```
System.out.printf((count == 1) ?  "%3d": "%11d", count);
```

You need not to add `count` again to the expression in conditional statement again.

Or to clear the confusion here let's split.

```
String format = (count == 1) ?  "%3d" : "%11d";
System.out.printf(format, count);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be possible with  'String.format' as follow

```
System.out.print((count==1)? String.format("%3d", count): String.format("%11d", count));
```